# Problems with COMODO update

Tags: updates

I have COMODO anti virus. I have been having problems updating it. I start to update, but then it tells me that it has failed and to check the internet connection. Everything with the connection is ok especially since I can post this question. Is anyone else having problems? If so what can be done. I have tried to reinstall it, and it does. Could it be that the COMODO site is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading/updating with apt-get, or how are you updating?

Comment: I have been using the update feature on the COMODO control window. It has worked just fine until about 3 or 4 days ago. Now no dice, but I did try to reinstall from the COMODO feature on this net site. Still no dice. It did install in good shape and was working just fine, but I wanted to see if it would update manually and I go the same response that I should check the net connection.

Comment: I would try doing an upgrade from apt-get (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, or do them separately in that order without `&&`) This will upgrade everything. If that doesn't work you could try doing a re-install or repair if it offers it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
sudo /opt/COMODO/cavupdater
```